# Number guessing game python (make the game ask to play every time)

Tags: python

```
import random

def game():
    number = random.randint(0, 10)
    guess = 0
    print("Guess a number from 0-10:")
    while number != guess:
        try:
            guess = int(input(""))
            if number != guess:
                print("you haven't guessed the number, keep trying")
            else:
                print("You guessed it!")
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer")

game()

choose = input("Would you like to play again?\n")
while choose == "yes":
    game()
    if choose == "no":
        break
```

I'm trying to add a feature where every time the game is won, the user has the option to play again, right now the game runs, then you win, it asks if you want to play again, you say yes, it runs again then you win and it runs again without asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose is only set one time, so the while-loop never breaks. You could simply add:

```py
choose = input("Would you like to play again?\n")

while choose == "yes":
    game()
    choose = input("Would you like to play again?\n")
    if choose == "no":
        break
```

Or somewhat more elegantly:

```py
choose = input("Would you like to play again?\n")

while choose != "no":
    game()
    choose = input("Would you like to play again?\n")
```

Comment: @OlegKniazev In general I would recommend putting the main game loop in a function as well and to restrict the possible input (users who are not you may choose to enter "n", "NO", etc. and wonder why the game never ends).

Comment: yeah, there are still many aspects I have to improve

Comment: Trying to improve is why we are all here! In your case you already have the structure setup in your game function and you simply need to scale it up in your main loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently only asking the user if he wants to play again **once**, and keep it going with the `while` loop. You should ask the user again after every time the game is played, like so:

```
choose = input("Would you like to play again?\n")
while choose == "yes":        
    game()
    choose = input("Would you like to play again?\n") #add this line
    if choose == "no":
        break
```

Comment: wow, can't believe it was this simple, thanks a lot!

Comment: @OlegKniazev With pleasure. Also check out Fnguyen's answer for a "prettier" solution as well (:

Comment: I tried it in my code and it asks me straight away if I want to play again
Guess a number from 0-10:
Would you like to play again?

Comment: @OlegKniazev change `guess= 0` to `guess = -1`, because the random number can be 0 and then you don't even play because `number = guess` at the start of the game

Comment: I noticed some times it would run and instantly say I guessed it!!